# setting the value of a cell in a range

Tags: excel, runtime-error, vba

I am having an issue with runtime error 91, Object variable or With block variable not set.  I am trying to write to a cell in a range.  Below is my latest code, with various methods I have tried to write to it.

Using .Value didn't work, nor did .Cells(1, 1).Value, nor did Set .Cells(1, 1).Value.  Not quite sure what I am missing here.

The value I am trying to write occasionally passes, it seems, but I would like to know exactly what I am doing wrong so I can prevent this from happening in the future.

Thanks,

Code in question, ElseIf is where it hangs up.  The If may or may not have problems...

```
Private Sub IncrementSPN()

    If Not tempSPNRange Is Nothing And Not isDuplicate Then
        ' Increment appropriate SPN family
        tempSPNRange.Value = tempSPN + 1
    ElseIf tempSPNRange Is Nothing And Not isDuplicate Then
        ' Don't increment anything, silly!
        Set tempSPNRange.Cells(1, 1).Value = tempSPNRange.Cells(1, 1).Value + 1
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: In this particular case, it looks at a cell.  If there is a value, it increments it.  If there is no value, it put the value of another cell in there, and increments it.  I use a range, because it can be one of three cells that needs incrementing, depending on other factors.  All the variables are globals, and assigned in other functions. This is basically the last Sub run before the userform finishes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If *tempSPNRange* has been **Dim'ed** as a Range, then within the ElseIf it needs to be **Set** to a group of cells within a worksheet and then values can be assigned to cells within the group.

Comment: I do set it in other functions; to Nothing if it doesn't need to be incremented, and to another Range + Offset if it does.  When it comes into this Sub, it should be a range that I can read/write values.  It seems to be working now; I think the isDuplicate variable (which I wasn't using) was throwing it off.  I will post back if I see any more problems while testing...